# Multiple triggers action on same row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problems in inserting data into four tables which are also referencing to a fact_table that contain identity_keys (AutoIncremental) of all four tables.

My Objective: 
When data is inserted into the four tables via my first code, triggers should insert the incremented key values to a fact_table called corporate_sales_help in the same row.

```
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| Time_ID |  CPS_ID |  COMPANY_ID | SECTOR_ID |
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|       1 |       3 |           1 |         3 |
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

What i got so far:

Data can be inserted into all four tables and the key is incremented, too.
The value of the incremented key is inserted into the fact-table as shown in the picture below

Insert statements for data:

```
INSERT INTO corporate_sales_view (year) VALUES (2005);
-- test
INSERT INTO corporate_sales_view (headquarter, company_name) values ('LONDON' ,'ToysRuS');
-- headquarter
INSERT INTO corporate_sales_view (sector) values ('Toys');
-- sector
INSERT INTO corporate_sales_view (sales_in_usd, sales_local) values (200000, 200003);
-- sales
```

One of the triggers :

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO corporate_sales_help (cps_id)
    VALUES (new.cps_id);
END
```

The result in the fact table so far: 
[result_in_fact_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hjWa.png)

What I really wanna see is all of the values should be in one row.

I have been searching for some hours on keywords like 'multiple trigger event/action on same row' , 'multiple insert same row' and so on.. but i couldn't find anything which could help to find a solution for my problem.

I am apologizing for my very bad english language.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making an INSERT.

So each trigger creates a new row.

You could use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but in your case what is the key?

Anyway there is no INSERT in same row, you have UPDATE for that.

The problem I see is that your actions are completely independent and you have independent triggers.

You should ask yourself: "What are the criteria to fill up a row?" and then implement a trigger that takes into account the fact that you have to update and not insert if you want data on the same row

---

The real problem is, what links those independent events together?

I guess it cannot be the time sequence, as what would happen if 2 users are creating records at the same time in the other 4 tables?

So the point is to identify what is the reason to link those events together, which probably will lead you to some kind of key.

The code that insert rows in those other tables is a single piece of code? Could not it insert those IDs in this table too then?

Regards

Comment: I don't really understand that , first when you do an insert a new row is created and now the second step is 'one duplicate key' to update that row.. but how can i implement it like this that the row where data was entered before from another trigger will be updated? I can't figure out any solution.. Maybe it will take me some time figuring out..

Comment: So you mean i could introduce a new key for the fact_table which is unique and could link those events together? But somehow i have to figure out how can i achieve the trigger referencing to this same unique key when doing inserting or update..

Comment: Yes, that is a possible way. The point is how those four tables and their insert are related.

Comment: Inserts are done at the same time...The problem is that the are more than four tables which are also connected to some other fact_tables...To have more flexibility.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand it.

Comment: Can't the code making the other inserts take care also of the help table. Anyway you should link all those events with a key.